# Using StandardCharset UTF-8 for Malformed Exception

Tags: java, character-encoding, nio

In the event of an occurrence of the following exception when reading a file,

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException - Input length = 1
```

what's the difference between the usage of below options in getting the Reader?

**Option 1:**

```
return Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF-8);
```

**Option 2:**

```
return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"));
```

**Option 1** still returns error while **Option 2** passes. How are both options different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How are both options different?

They are different because the javadoc of [`Files.newBufferedReader(Path path, Charset cs)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) says:

> The Reader methods that read from the file throw IOException if a malformed or unmappable byte sequence is read.

The javadoc of [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) doesn't say that. It is *lenient*, and they decided to fix that flaw when they added NIO.2 to the language in Java 7.